# How to handle less than 4 feet of overlap top and bottom plate (Framing)

Tags: framing, studs, load-bearing

My house has had pretty extensive termite damage across two bedrooms that are side by side.  The termites have chewed up several studs as well as sections of the top and bottom plates.  At first I thought the top plate was fine but when I removed the bottom plate I realized there was extensive damage and it needs to be replaced.

When I replaced all damaged sections of the bottom plate I did one continuous piece in the middle and had a clear 4 foot distance from any ends.  I ensured a stud was under the split and even put a metal stud clip on each one for added protection.

The problem is now the top plate.  My plan is to bring to the very end of room one and split in the middle to give me > 4 foot overlap between any bottom plate splits.  The issue is in room 2 I don't really have much room.  I can achieve a 2.5 foot overlap before I have to mess with pulling electrical, maybe a 3 foot if I take to the very end.

The "correct" thing to do would be to tear into room 3 (the living room) but that is not practical.  Is there a code compliant, or at the very least reasonably correct way to handle this?  I planned on putting a tie plate over the top plate and nailing the hell out of it on both sides.

This is an exterior load bearing wall.  State is Florida if it means anything.

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember properly, when subcontractors used to cut through the plates to add ducting or waste lines, the inspector allowed a 4 ft. metal strap to be installed to tie the top plates back together again. Just on one plate the the other was still good for nailing.

[Simpson](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Simpson-Strong-Tie-ST-16-5-16-in-20-Gauge-Galvanized-Strap-Tie/1003095036) makes straps for this type of install. I tried to upload a pic, but got an error about server failure or something like that

Comment: Thanks.  I'll just strap.  The issue with this is the overlap between top and bottom is < 4 ft.  To be honest with the straps it probably will be stronger.